# Aggregating statistics into JSON in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

So I am trying to calculate overview statistics into JSON, but am having trouble wrangling them into a query.

There are 2 tables:

```
appointments
- time timestamp
- patients int


assignments
- user_id int
- appointment_id int
```

I want to calculate the number of patients by user, by hour for the day. Ideally, it would look like this:

```
[ 
  {hour: "2015-07-01T08:00:00.000Z", assignments: [
    {user_id: 123, patients: 3}, 
    {user_id: 456, patients: 10}, 
    {user_id: 789, patients: 4},
  ]},
  {hour: "2015-07-01T09:00:00.000Z", assignments: [
    {user_id: 456, patients: 1},
    {user_id: 789, patients: 6}
  ]},
  {hour: "2015-07-01T10:00:00.000Z", assignments: []}
  ...
]
```

I got kind of close:

```
with assignments_totals as (
    select user_id,sum(patients),date_trunc('hour',appointments.time) as hour
    from assignments
    inner join appointments on appointments.id = assignments.appointment_id
    group by date_trunc('hour',sales.time),user_id
  ), hours as (
    select to_char(date_trunc('hour',time),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:00:00.000Z') as hour, array_to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT assignment_totals)) as patients
    from appointments 
    left join assignment_totals on date_trunc('hour',sales.time) = assignment_totals.hour
    where time >= '2015-07-01T07:00:00.000Z' and time < '2015-07-02T07:00:00.000Z' 
    group by date_trunc('hour',time)
    order by date_trunc('hour',time) 
  )
  select array_to_json(array_agg(hours)) as hours from hours;
```

Which outputs:

```
[ 
  {hour: "2015-07-01T08:00:00.000Z", assignments: [
    {user_id: 123, patients: 3, hour: "2015-07-01T08:00:00.000Z" }, 
    {user_id: 456, patients: 10, hour: "2015-07-01T08:00:00.000Z"}, 
    {user_id: 789, patients: 4, hour: "2015-07-01T08:00:00.000Z"},
  ]},
  {hour: "2015-07-01T09:00:00.000Z", assignments: [
    {user_id: 456, patients: 1, hour: "2015-07-01T09:00:00.000Z"},
    {user_id: 789, patients: 6, hour: "2015-07-01T09:00:00.000Z"}
  ]},
  {hour: "2015-07-01T10:00:00.000Z", assignments: [null]}
  ...
]
```

While this works, there are 2 issues, which may or may not be independent of each other:

1. If there are no appointments that hour, I still want the hour to be included in the array (like 10AM in the example), but to have an empty "assignments" array. Right now it puts a null in there, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it while still keeping the hours in there.
2. I have to have the hour included in the assignments entries along with user_id and appointments because I need it to join the assignments_totals query to the hours query. But it's unnecessary  because it's already in the parent.
3. I feel like it should be able to be done in 1 cte and 1 query and now I'm using 2 cte's... but can't figure out how to condense it and make it work.

I wanted to do something like

```
  hours as (
    select to_char(date_trunc('hour',time),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:00:00.000Z') as hour, sum(appointments.patients) OVER(partition by assignments.user_id) as appointments
    from appointments 
    left join assignments on appointments.id = assignments.appointment_id
    where time >= '2015-07-01T07:00:00.000Z' and time < '2015-07-02T07:00:00.000Z'  
    group by date_trunc('hour',time)
    order by date_trunc('hour',time) 
  )
  select array_to_json(array_agg(hours)) as hours from hours
```

but i can't get it to work without giving me a "attribute must be in the group by or aggregate function error.

Anyone know how to fix any of these issues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your last query seems to be in conflating [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-window.html) with [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).  Window functions use the `OVER` syntax, and they do not in themselves require `GROUP BY` when there are other fields in the `SELECT` clause.  Aggregate functions, on the other hand, use `GROUP BY` when there are other (non-aggregate-function) fields in the `SELECT` clause.  One practical consequence of this difference is that window functions are not automatically `DISTINCT`.

The issue with `NULL` values resulting from the window function can be resolved with a simple `COALESCE` such that zero is used instead of null.

So, to write your query using a window function, use something like:

```
WITH hours AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT to_char(date_trunc('hour', ap.time), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:00:00.000Z') AS hour,
           COALESCE(SUM(ap.patients) OVER (PARTITION BY asgn.user_id), 0) AS appointment_count
    FROM   appointments ap
    LEFT JOIN assignments asgn ON ap.id = asgn.appointment_id
    WHERE  ap.time >= '2015-07-01T07:00:00.000Z'
    AND    ap.time < '2015-07-02T07:00:00.000Z'
)
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(hours)) AS hours
FROM   hours
ORDER BY hour
```

With an aggregate function:

```
WITH hours AS
(
    SELECT to_char(date_trunc('hour', ap.time), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:00:00.000Z') AS hour,
           SUM(COALESCE(ap.patients, 0)) AS appointment_count,
           asgn.user_id
    FROM   appointments ap
    LEFT JOIN assignments asgn ON ap.id = asgn.appointment_id
    WHERE  ap.time >= '2015-07-01T07:00:00.000Z'
    AND    ap.time < '2015-07-02T07:00:00.000Z'
    GROUP BY asgn.user_id, to_char(date_trunc('hour', ap.time), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:00:00.000Z')
)
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(hours)) AS hours
FROM   hours
ORDER BY hour
```

My syntax may not be quite correct, so double-check before using this solution or one like it (and feel free to edit to correct any errors).

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew, I forgot I could coalesce them to 0. I still want to be able to filter so that there are no assignment entries with patients < 1.

Answer (score 1):

Most of my frustration with this came because I was not looking at the Postgres 9.4 documentation, which has new functions for dealing with json.

The solution I found builds upon the original query, but then breaks the assignments array down using json_array_elements, filters using where, then builds it back up again. It seems pointless to have essentially:

```
json_agg(json_array_elements(json_agg(*)))
```

But it makes very little performance difference and gets me where I need to go. Feel free to comment if you find a better solution! It should also be possible in <9.4 using array_agg and unnest but I was having trouble because I was trying to unnest a record type returned from my CTE, instead of an actual row type with column definitions.

```
  with assignment_totals as (
    select 
      date_trunc('hour',appointments.time) as hour, 
      user_id, 
      coalesce(sum(patients),0) as patients
    from appointments
    left outer join assignments on appointment.id = assignments.appointment_id
    where time >= '2015-07-01T07:00:00.000Z' and time < '2015-07-02T07:00:00.000Z' 
    group by date_trunc('hour',appointments.time),user_id
  ), hours as (
    select 
      to_char(assignment_totals.hour,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:00:00.000Z') as hour,
      (
        select coalesce(json_agg(json_build_object('user_id',(t->'user_id'),'patients',(t->'patients')) order by (t->>'user_id')),'[]'::json) 
        from json_array_elements(json_agg(assignment_totals)) t 
        where (t->>'patients') != '0'
      ) as patients
    from assignment_totals 
    group by assignment_totals.hour
    order by assignment_totals.hour
  )
  select array_to_json(array_agg(hours)) as hours from hours
```

Thanks to Andrew for pointing out that I can coalesce nulls to 0. But I still want to filter out entries where patients = 0. This solves all my problems by giving me the ability to filter them out with a where, and then gives me the ability to take out the time by building a new json object with json_build_object.